# Encoding Turkish char on Http Post method with Java

Tags: java, http, url, encoding, turkish

I have a problem Turkish Character encoding 
I send a xml document with web services on http post methods but When I encoding Turkish Character(Ğ,Ş ı...) asci code java translate &#230 etc.

this time url conneciton is cut data's  other partial because & is mean new attribute 
so how to solve this problem what can I do  before send on java???

Comment: I guess the answer is to encode the data explicitly as UTF-8, however to get a valid answer you should post a small code sample showing how you send your XML document on HTTP.

Comment: if I use Utf-8 for example my url : http:10.11.11/dasd?&id&password&<root><item1>shoes</item1><item2>ğişçöĞİÖÇ</item2></root>    so this time url not accept Turkish Character  but i sender character asci code my url transform   http:10.11.11/dasd?&id&password&<root><item1>shoes</item1><item2>&#210;&#210;&#210;&#211;şçöĞİÖÇ</item2></root> so it saw new attribute

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are sending the XML as part of the URL? In that case you'll need to percent-encode it (see RFC 3986)